# Error while building the solution in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've created my project in vs2008.It works fine.But when i opened the solution and try to build it in vs2012 i am getting the following error in TransactionDB.dbml page.

```
a partial method may not have multiple defining declarations
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513873.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net supports partial methods.
It means you write a definition in one part of the partial class and the implementation in another. Like this:

```
    partial class MyClass
    {
        partial void MyPartialMethod(string s);
    }

    // This part can be in a separate file. 
    partial class MyClass
    {
        // Comment out this method and the program will still compile. 
        partial void MyPartialMethod(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
        }
    }
```

In your case I you have the two definitions of the partial method causing the compiler to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Source [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513873.aspx)

The defining declaration of a partial method is the part that specifies the method signature, but not the implementation (method body). A partial method must have exactly one defining declaration for each unique signature. Each overloaded version of a partial method must have its own defining declaration.

**To correct this error**

Remove all except one defining declaration for the partial method.

**Example**

```
// cs0756.cs
using System;

    public partial class C
    {
        partial void Part();
        partial void Part(); // CS0756
        public static int Main()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```